# Plugging custom transport into gRPC

Tags: c++, grpc

Let‘s assume we develop a custom low level transport for gRPC. How can we “plug it” into the gRPC c++ API so that we can use it for a Channel?

Answer (score 8):

I'm working on a doc that will soon appear at https://github.com/grpc/grpc/ but here's a preview:

[gRPC transports](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/core/ext/transport) plug in below the core API (one level below the C++ API). You can write your transport in C or C++ though; currently all the transports are nominally written in C++ though they are idiomatically C. The existing transports are:

- [HTTP/2](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2)
- [Cronet](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/core/ext/transport/cronet)
- [In-process](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/core/ext/transport/inproc)

Among these, the in-process is likely the easiest to understand, though arguably also the least similar to a "real" sockets-based transport.

In the gRPC core implementation, a fundamental struct is the `grpc_transport_stream_op_batch` which represents a collection of stream operations sent to a transport. The ops in a batch can include:

- send_initial_metadata

  - Client: initate an RPC
  - Server: supply response headers
- recv_initial_metadata

  - Client: get response headers
  - Server: accept an RPC
- send_message (zero or more) : send a data buffer
- recv_message (zero or more) : receive a data buffer
- send_trailing_metadata

  - Client: half-close indicating that no more messages will be coming
  - Server: full-close providing final status for the RPC
- recv_trailing_metadata: get final status for the RPC

  - Server extra: This op shouldn't actually be considered complete until the server has also sent trailing metadata to provide the other side with final status
- cancel_stream: Attempt to cancel an RPC
- collect_stats: Get stats

One or more of these ops are grouped into a batch. Applications can start all of a call's ops in a single batch, or they can split them up into multiple batches. Results of each batch are returned asynchronously via a completion queue.

Internally, we use callbacks to indicate completion. The surface layer creates a callback when starting a new batch and sends it down the filter stack along with the batch. The transport must invoke this callback when the batch is complete, and then the surface layer returns an event to the application via the completion queue. Each batch can have up to 3 callbacks:

- recv_initial_metadata_ready (called by the transport when the recv_initial_metadata op is complete)
- recv_message_ready (called by the transport when the recv_message op is complete)
- on_complete (called by the transport when the entire batch is complete)

The transport's job is to sequence and interpret various possible interleavings of the basic stream ops. For example, a sample timeline of batches would be:

1. Client send_initial_metadata: Initiate an RPC with a path (method) and authority
2. Server receive_initial_metadata: accept an RPC
3. Client send_message: Supply the input proto for the RPC
4. Server receive_message: Get the input proto from the RPC
5. Client send_trailing_metadata: This is a half-close indicating that the client will not be sending any more messages
6. Server receive_trailing_metadata: The server sees this from the client and knows that it will not get any more messages. This won't complete yet though, as described above.
7. Server send_initial_metadata, send_message, send_trailing_metadata: A batch can contain multiple ops, and this batch provides the RPC response headers, response content, and status. Note that sending the trailing metadata will also complete the server's receive of trailing metadata.
8. Client recv_initial_metadata: The number of ops in one side of the batch has no relation with the number of ops on the other side of the batch. In this case, the client is just collecting the response headers.
9. Client recv_message, recv_trailing_metadata: Get the data response and status

In addition to these basic stream ops, the transport must handle cancellations of a stream at any time and pass their effects to the other side. The transport must perform operations like pings and statistics that are used to shape transport-level characteristics like flow control (see, for example, their use in the HTTP/2 transport).

Comment: Thanks for that answer! Most of the details I already figured out looking at the transport implementations. The question was rather: If I want to hook in my OWN transport that fulfills all this contract, how do I inject it through the C++ API...

Comment: There is C++ doxygen doc for this topic, https://grpc.io/grpc/core/md_doc_core_transport_explainer.html

Answer (score 0):

Regarding C++ API: Most of the existing custom transports are done by creating their own credentials C++ types and use those to enable the new transport.