# Precise and complete language-agnostic specification of gRPC

Tags: grpc

Is there a full specification of the gRPC protocol, like RFC, that could be followed by an implementer? I am looking for document(s) that would allow me to implement gRPC that can interoperate with the official implementations (and currently supported transports).

Different aspects are described conceptually in [1](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/CONCEPTS.md), [2](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/concepts.html), [3](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/error.html), [4](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-WEB.md), [5](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47190598/837811), but I am wondering if it is enough to just replicate that behavior and have a code that will work with the reference implementation, or there is something undocumented that is going on under the hood?

Comment: Your 5th link is the "source of truth" spec for the main gRPC protocol: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md

Comment: @StanleyCheung Thanks!

Comment: You may also be interested to read/watch https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/15460 for a higher-level/semantic specification. It has stalled a bit, but most of what slowed it down was bikeshedding over the terms to use.

Comment: @EricAnderson Thank you!!