# Can a TCP socket client and protobuf talk to a gRPC server?

Tags: sockets, tcp, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have two machines talking to each other over TCP, with Machine A using Machine B's service. Ideally I'd love to use an RPC framework for this. gRPC comes to mind since we already use protobuf.

However, Machine A already uses an external library that wraps TCP sockets for communication, so that the client app code can only send raw bytes (encoded in protobuf) to Machine B. So I wonder if I could adapt the code to working with the gRPC server on Machine B.

Comment: A client using raw sockets isn't a TCP client. Why does one machine have to use raw sockets? No IP stack?

Comment: @user207421 I updated my question. Would it make more sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gRPC is built on top of http/2, and you can theoretically use any kind of connection (e.g. domain sockets, named pipes) to communicate using gRPC, so it is certainly possible. In fact, at least in go, gRPC uses TCP by default.

If the requirement is only that machine A communicates using TCP sockets, but you can use external libraries, then it should be fairly easy to use the gRPC library of the language of your choice to implement the client/server interaction on top of the raw TCP sockets.

On the other hand, if you **can not** use the gRPC library, while still possible you would have to implement the gRPC protocol yourself, and possibly the http/2 one as well if you can't use any external library; this would likely be a lot of work, and you may be better off creating a simpler, ad-hoc RPC protocol for your use case.

**EDIT**

The updated question makes the requirements clearer. If you need to use a specific TCP library, but you can use gRPC on top of that, then I think the difficulty of the task really depends on the programming language.

For instance, in go it would be as easy as creating a wrapper struct, implement the `net.conn` interface for it, and use it with the `withDialer` option when creating the client. In c++ it looks like it would be more difficult and entail [implementing a custom transport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126989/plugging-custom-transport-into-grpc) (altough I'm not that familiar with the c++ gRPC API so there may be an easier way)

Comment: Thanks. Machine A does use another external library that wraps a TCP client so that I can only send raw bytes in my app code.